# Emacs + visual line numbers + folding + visual fill column mode

Tags: evil, code-folding, line-numbers, visual-line-mode

Relative line numbers for me it's a little bit painful topic. I'm using evil (spacemacs) and I want to jump between lines by in vim style like `10j`, `4k` etc.
Is it possible to get line numbers behavior in emacs just like in vim?

There is two mutually exclusive problems for `visual` and `relative` line numbers mode in emacs.

1. Visual line numbers works great with folding. But when test wraps by `visual-fill-column-mode`, visual line numbers assigns a number to non-existent line. And from now I can't just moving between lines correctly because of related picture.
   [image]
2. In another hand relative line numbers solve the problem above, and it works just fine, but... until the moment when I fold something. Imagine, in picture below I want jump to one of `Another long test topic`. How should I do this?
   [image]

So, is there any solution for this? I've spent a lot of time to googling it, but my efforts still have no result.

Sorry for my English.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

I've FINALLY got solution for this, but there is not related with line numbers. 
All what I've done is just set another functions to `j`, `k` for evil. And it works almost perfect.

God, I'm sooo happy now.
There is solution for spacemacs

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9557#issuecomment-327976596